# How to upgrade symfony minor version (4.1 to 4.2)

Tags: php, symfony, upgrade

I just want to know which is the proper way to upgrade symfony a minor version.

In the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html it says just to upgrade symfony/symfony package in composer, but I don't have this package, instead I have various symfony/framework-bundle, symfony/form, etc.

What I've done so far is to upgrade all symfony/XXX to the new version.

Also I had to create a new project with the 4.2 version in other folder, and copy the files `.gitignore`, `public/index.php`, `config/bootstrap.php` and `src/kernel.php` to the original project as these files has changed from 4.1 to 4.2, but I think this should not be the way to do it.

Should I have to remove all symfony/XX packages and replace them with symfony/symfony?

Will this upgrade also the files `public/index.php`, `config/bootstra.php`, etc?

Thank you

Comment: For a fresh Symfony 4 project all you need to do is to update the require attribute down at the bottom of composer.json in the extra/symfony section and then do a composer update.  Files like index.php are not going to change.  The process is perhaps a bit different if you updated a legacy project from Symfony 3.  The fact that you mentioned the bootstrap file makes me think this is the case.  If so, I would suggest creating a fresh 4.2 project and then use the resulting composer.json as a starting point for your legacy project.

Comment: Hi  @Cerad, I've checked and the project was created in Symfony 4.0, not 3

Comment: Interesting.  Think I'm going to bow out here.  Seems to be some fairly significant composer.json changes going on, perhaps with Flex playing a role.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was updating to 4.2 from 4.1.11 and some new files from 4.2 for some reason weren't automatically created. Also, there are a few changes in environment files that I consider very important.

I think the best and cleanest way to do this to do the following:

**Instructions**

1. Update `composer.json`

```
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.2.*"
    }
}
```

2. Update dependencies `composer update "symfony/*"`
3. Create a new `config/bootstrap.php` file with [this code](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/config/bootstrap.php).
4. Update `public/index.php` file with [this code](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/public/index.php).
5. Update `.gitignore`

*Remove*

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
/.env
```

*Add*

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
/.env.local
/.env.local.php
/.env.*.local
```

6. Rename `.env` to `.env.local`
7. Rename `.env.dist` to `.env`

**-- Update 30/05/19 --**

8. Update `bin/console` file with [this code](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/console/3.3/bin/console)

---

**Testing with PHPUnit**

Follow this extra steps if you are using **PHPUnit** in your application (**Recommended**):

1. Create a new `.env.test` and set your variables for test environment.
2. Update `phpunit.xml.dist` with [this code](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/phpunit-bridge/3.3/phpunit.xml.dist).

---

**Important**

You should notify about the environment files changes to your team and they should make a backup of their current configuration before pulling the changes because it will override the `.env` file.

If you need more information about this solution please read: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html

Comment: Thank you! I updated a 4.1 system that was pre NOV update and was success. Happy to be at 4.2.7 now.

Comment: I think you forgot the changes to bin/console, as detailed here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html
the updated file is here: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/console/3.3/bin/console

Comment: @Emanuele You're right, I updated the answer. Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your composer.json. I just did same and only had to raise the minor. Then I’ve ran composer update and I succeeded.

I always follow the guides.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/UPGRADE-4.2.md

Comment: I try to follow the instructions, but as I've said, there are files that changes from a version to another and I dont't see where it says that these files must be updated manually.