# How to upgrade Symfony minor version from 4.2 to 4.3

Tags: symfony4, symfony-4.2, symfony-4.3

I need to upgrade Symfony minor version from 4.2 to 4.3.

I check the official document and find there is only 4.0 to 4.1 and there is no description for which files should be edited manually. I follow the document and find that is not clear enough to do it.

I read the document on Stackoverflow before and upgraded it for 4.1 to 4.2 successfully and I want something like this.

[How to upgrade symfony minor version (4.1 to 4.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241640/how-to-upgrade-symfony-minor-version-4-1-to-4-2)

Comment: Have you tried `composer update`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478570/how-to-update-symfony-4-1-to-4-3 ;)