# How to update symfony with flex?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I think my question may be stupid, but I can’t figure out how to upgrade my Symfony project from version 4.1. * to version 4.3. *.

I tried to touch the composer.json. But it sends me an error message... Does anyone have the solution?

composer.json

I had this :

```
"conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.1.*"
        }
    }
```

I changed by that:

```
"conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
```

Version 4.4 does not download or update...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extra.symfony.require` is for performance reasons, as `symfony` has too many versions and update may take a long time. To update project you also need to add `4.3.*` constraint to the `require` section:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*"
},
```

Comment: yes sorry it's gone to version 4.3 seen on the doc. How do you get to 4.3 ?